# Почему необходимо использовать синтаксис С?(Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

Начал изучать программирование на C++ и захотел сделать консольное приложение для нахождения площади круга. Решил для этого подключить число Pi и Microsoft(https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/math-constants?view=msvc-160) сказал мне сделать это так:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES // for C++
#include <cmath>
```

Сделал таким образом, но Visual ругается, мол идентификатор не M_PI не определен.

Сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>

int main(){
    std::cout << "FUCK THIS WORLD!!!" << "\n";
    double R;
    double S;
    std::cout << "enter radius" << "\n";
    std::cin >> R;
    S = M_PI * pow(R, 2); //в этой строке выдает ошибку
    std::cout << "Arrea = " << S << " sm^2";
    return 0;
}
```

При этом, если делать через

```
#include <math.h>
```

, то все ОК, вообще проблем нет.
Может кто объяснить, из-за чего такая проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Директивы, контролирующие библиотечные заголовочные файлы, следует задавать **строго до** подключения любых заголовочных файлов (обычно такие директивы выносятся в отдельный приоритетный заголовочный файл или задаются посредством опций компилятора):

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
```

Иначе в месте добавления директивы целевой заголовочный файл может оказаться уже включенным и директива не возымеет эффекта.

Также следует обращать внимание на то, чтобы прекомпилируемый заголовочный файл использовал строго тот же набор директив.

Answer (score 1):

А вот так случилось. Ну не подвезли в плюсы число пи в удобном плюсовом виде. Надо было функции Бесселя подвозить или auto_ptr подвозить-вывозить. А до числа пи добрались только в 20 стандарте...

`std::numbers::pi` - http://eel.is/c++draft/numbers

А то этого либо math.h, либо ручками, с нужной точностью. К тому же в некоторых студиях это не сразу и работает - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065359/m-pi-flagged-as-undeclared-identifier